# Is it possible to block web-content (images) for users that don't match one ip?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I have e.g. two pictures:

- foobar.png *(deny from all except one ip)*
- foobar_preview.png *(allow for every one)*

Now I want to deny the content for all clients except one

Now my `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
<Files ~ "\.png$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>

<Files ~ "\_preview.png$">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Files>
```

So I want to allow the `"\.png$"` files only for one server (so one IP-Adress)

It there a way to realize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Allow from IP` directive:

```
<Files ~ "\.png$">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from 11.22.33.44
  Deny from all
</Files>

<Files ~ "\_preview.png$">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: I tried it already before I asked here - I don't know why - but it don't works..
I tried it with the server IP and also with my local ISP-IP.

Comment: Yes this should be your client's public IP not the server's IP. So when you request `http://domain.com/abc.png` you get forbidden?

Comment: I got "Forbidden" (403) everytime (on each ip), but found the bug: I had to change the **Order** to `Order Deny,Allow` instead `Order Allow,Deny`

Now it works lovely. Thanks!